Can't access property "__webglFramebuffer"
If we start the Viewer, but a navigation happens in between, we have the following problem.

This would be not such a problem if it would not log it only once, but it seems there is some kind of loop, and we are getting a lot of those errors. Also, it impacts the browser performance as well.
The following message also gets printed, but I would not know how we can avoid that leak.

This seems to happen from the Version 7.90.0 onwards. With the Version 7.89.0 we would get the following error:

But this error gets logged only once, and we experienced no performance issues.
Will there be fix in some upcoming versions, or how could we tackle this issue?
Steps to reproduce:

Start up a viewer instance
Quickly navigate back
Wait for errors in console

Update
We already call the folllowing functions on the ngDestroyHook:

viewer.tearDown()
viewer.current?.uninitialize()
this.viewer.finish()
Autodesk.Viewing.shutdown();


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Make sure you access the viewer only until the component isn't destroyed. In our case, we made some async initializing and destroyed the component before the initializing has been done.

You need to destroy the viewer instance, once the component gets unmounted, inside the ngOnDestroy hook.
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.viewer && this.viewer.impl.selector) {
      this.viewer.tearDown();
      this.viewer.finish();
      this.viewer = null;
    }
  }


We already do (try) this, but if throws the following error "can't access property "clearSelection", this.impl.selector is undefined"
and afterward the other errors as described in the question

@mudo121, I just updated my answer by adding && this.viewer.impl.selector in the if condition, could you check again?

Yes that was a good hint. I've changed my code as well to wait until the viewer is set and so on, but still I'm getting the __webGlBufferProblem exception. I see though, that the teardown and finish are working properly. Also, my solution works well with the Version 7.89.0 but not with 7.97.0.

It did not matter which version I used (v7.89 or v7.97 - the latest one at the moment) I got similar results in my very simple vanilla html page.
If I remove the Viewer component from the DOM while it's loading a model I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'tBodies')
    at SettingsPanel.addRow (viewer3D.js:60936:90)
    at SettingsPanel.addSliderV2 (viewer3D.js:61008:24)
    at ViewerSettingsPanel.addSliderV2 (viewer3D.js:65537:98)
    at ViewerSettingsPanel.initScrollSpeed (viewer3D.js:65747:17)
    at ViewerSettingsPanel.createNavigationPanel (viewer3D.js:65702:42)
    at new ViewerSettingsPanel (viewer3D.js:65333:8)
    at GuiViewer3D.createSettingsPanel (viewer3D.js:57670:23)
    at GuiViewer3D.initModelTools (viewer3D.js:57683:8)
    at GuiViewer3D.createUI (viewer3D.js:57254:8)
    at createUI (viewer3D.js:57154:12)

If I set the Viewer size to 0 while it's loading a model I get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '__webglFramebuffer')
    at WebGLRenderer.initFrameBufferMRT (viewer3D.js:105990:56)
    at WebGLRenderer.setRenderTarget (viewer3D.js:106090:12)
    at LMVRenderer.setRenderTarget (viewer3D.js:88815:59)
    at RenderContext._render (viewer3D.js:94489:14)
    at RenderContext.renderScenePart (viewer3D.js:94601:12)
    at Array.cmdSceneAfterRender (viewer3D.js:26104:15)
    at RenderCommandSystem.executeCommandList (viewer3D.js:25801:42)
    at Viewer3DImpl.tick (viewer3D.js:26791:10)
    at animloop (viewer3D.js:26830:17)

(if I call viewer.impl.resize(0, 0) more than once the same error gets into an endless loop)
Here is the html page I used for testing: https://github.com/adamenagy/Container/blob/master/revit-reload.html
If these do not help narrow down the issue on your side then the best would be if you could provide a minimal (as small and simple as possible) sample for us to use to reproduce the issue on our side.
